# What is the area of the triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles, area

I managed to solve this question using trigonometry. But I wondered if there'd be anyway of doing it using only synthetic geometry. Here it is.

> Let $ABC$ be a right isosceles triangle of hypotenuse $AB$. Let also $\Gamma$ be the semicircle whose diameter is the line segment $AC$ such that $\Gamma\cap\overline{AB} = \{A\}$. Consider $P\in\Gamma$ with $PC = k$, with $k \leq AC$. Find the area of triangle $PBC$.

Here is my interpretation of the picture:
[image]

I managed to get the solution via trigonometry as below.

[image]

Then, the area $S$ requested is:

$$\begin{align} S &= \displaystyle\frac{PC\cdot BC\cdot \sin(90^\circ + \beta)}{2}\\
&= \displaystyle\frac{k\cdot d\cdot \cos\beta}{2}\\
&= \displaystyle\frac{k\cdot d\cdot \frac{k}{d}}{2}\\
&= \displaystyle\frac{k^2}{2}.\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Could you please draw a figure?  It seems there are an infinite number of $\Gamma$s that obey your stated constraints, and not all will allow your problem to be solved.

Comment: Hey! Hmmmm, I don't see these ambiguities you mention. Because after drawing that right isosceles triangle, there are only two ways of drawing the mentioned semicircle: one intersecting AB in two points and the other one interescting it only in point A.

Comment: Please include your trigonometric solution. It may save someone time in devising a synthetic solution.

Comment: But yeah, I can put a picture the way I've drawn. One minute.

Comment: Indeed, I concur with @Blue's request.  Please include your trigonometric solution. Not just your result, but your work to get it.

Comment: Working on it!!

Comment: Thanks for editing and improving your post, @Italo !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

$$|\triangle PBC| = \frac12|CP||BQ| = \frac12k^2$$

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Draw the parallel line BX || AP and extend PC to meet it at X. Note that $\angle XCB = 90 - \beta = \gamma$. Along with CA = CB, the right triangles APC and CBX are congruent, which leads to $CP = BX = k$.

Thus, the area of CPB is

$$Area_{CPB}=\frac12 CP\cdot BX = \frac12k^2$$

Answer (score 3):

Let us find the altitude of point $P$, a is a leg. Intersection of the circles $x^2+h^2=k^2, x^2+(h-\frac{a}{2})^2=(\frac{a}{2})^2 $

$h=\frac{k^2}{a} $

$A\; PBC=\frac{1}{2}*ah=\frac{k^2}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $PD$ be a perpendicular from $P$ to the line $BC$.

Thus, since a line $BC$ is a tangent to the circle and $\measuredangle DCP=\measuredangle PAC$, we see that $\Delta DCP\sim\Delta PAC,$

which gives:
$$\frac{PD}{k}=\frac{k}{AC}$$ or
$$PD=\frac{k^2}{AC}.$$
Id est, $$S_{\Delta PBC}=\frac{1}{2}BC\cdot PD=\frac{1}{2}BC\cdot\frac{k^2}{AC}=\frac{k^2}{2}.$$